# Cultivation manhua/manhwa in which the main character is put in a cage and his astral form goes on adventures with his female master

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I remember reading this quite a while ago. The main character is put in a cage in the middle of town and his astral form goes on adventures with his female master (he has more than one female master). Later on, he returns to his body and travels to one of his master's sects and joins it.
-Edit-I believe I read it between 2019-2020 or it might have been 2021 sorry this isn’t specific I have really bad memory when it comes to years and dates.
The art style is somewhat similar to “Beyond Myriad Peoples/ Above ten thousand people” or “I’m actually a cultivation big shot”

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

It’s I return from the heavens and worlds

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain how it matches the details provided in the question?

Comment: Yes that’s the one, thank you so much.